# Sprockets not refreshing with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sprockets

I'm using Sprockets from my Sinatra app. I have the following set:

```
set :sprockets, Sprockets::Environment.new(root) { |env|
      env.append_path(root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets'))
      env.append_path(root.join('app', 'assets', 'javascripts'))
      env.append_path(root.join('app', 'assets', 'images'))
    }
```

Everything works fine, but when I run my app, the CSS styles aren't updated without me restarting the server. Is there any way to have these assets compiled on the fly in development?

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Sinatra don't [reload](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading) anything between requests. Using [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) should solve your problem.

Comment: Reloading the Ruby isn't the problem. Reloading the ruby code is set in the application and works fine. 

configure :development do
  register Sinatra::Reloader
 end

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I don't guess why you face that problem. I used sinatra with sprockets too on the base  from https://github.com/jch/sinatra-sprockets and «it just works». So you could try it, and I think it would be work for you too.